# Can't unmount or resize partition sda5

Tags: partitioning

I'm very new to Ubuntu and I can't see my hard drive partitions in computer then I tried to see partition using GPartrd software then I found that 3 partition but couldn't unmount or resize `/dev/sda5` (186.26 GIB) which is mounted on home.

How to do it?

Comment: can you update your  question with output of `lsblk`

Comment: You cannot unmount or resize your home partition if you are using the system. You will notice a key symbol next to the partition which means it is locked due to it being in use. In order to manipulate your home partition, you must live boot Ubuntu using an USB or CD and then run GParted from your live instance.

Comment: If you show me a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted` view of /dev/sda I'll take a look for you, and then make some recommendations.

Comment: Dear  Sumeet Deshmukh, Thanks & followed your instruction and b  booted  up the machine with Ubuntu usb pen drive  but in this stage I couldn't find GParted software. If you don't mind I can send you a  screen shot of gparted  if it is not a problem to you please advice me to how do I send that screen shot for your kind consideration - B-rgds,

Comment: Dear  heynnema Please advise me, how do I show that that screen shot for your consideration.